# Selecting a last word from a string in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath

I just want to take the last element from a string which is like this "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd" in xslt.

Out put should be "ddd" irrecspective of '-'s.

Comment: Search for "XSLT string split"

Comment: Hey...i used tokenize function and it worked.Thank you so much...

Answer (score 16):

**XSLT/Xpath 2.0** - using the [tokenize()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) function to split the string on the "-" and then use a predicate filter to select the last item in the sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize('aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd','-')[last()]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT/XPath 1.0** - using [a recursive template](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N7240.html#d10122e532) to look for the last occurrence of "-" and selecting the substring following it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="marker" select="'-'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
        <xsl:param name="input" />
        <xsl:param name="marker" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($input,$marker)">
                <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
                    <xsl:with-param name="input"
          select="substring-after($input,$marker)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="marker" select="$marker" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$input" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I was trying to write a regex to select the last item of a string, with no luck. `/ \w+$/` worked on the regex tester, but I couldn't adapt it to XPath. Your implementation of the _hyphen_ and `[last()] ` worked just right.